# Api : Express : throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I have just started with api building using express but getting below error.

[image: err]
 below is my code. please help.

Server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const profile = require('./routes/api/profile');
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');
const app = express();

//DB config

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

//connet to MongoDB

mongoose
    .connect(db)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello Ajas Bakran'));

//Use Routes

app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/profile', profile);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

users.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({msg:'Hello Users'}));

module.exports = router;
```

profile.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({msg:'Hello profile'}));

module.exports = router;
```

posts.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({msg:'Hello posts'}));

module.exports = router;
```

I refered few answers on stackoverflow, but moslty solution to that was having `module.exports = router;` this line at the end. but i do have the line present already still i get the same error. Really not sure what is going wrong

Comment: The above code looks ok. please post the full error msg that you are getting.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty i have added the screenshot of error..please have a look

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see I think you need to re-write this portion:

```
router.route('/')
```

instead of

```
router.get
```

Usually these types of error originate from non properly exported router.